# What is it called when one adds a property to an object literal outside of the object literals braces?

Tags: javascript

Take this code for example:

```
var o = {
    prop: 37
};

o.f = "hello";
```

Here, the property "f" is created **outside** of the braces of the object literal.  I'm used to setting an object's properties (like "f" here) **inside** the braces like this:

```
var o = {
    prop: 37,
    f: "hello"
};
```

Is there a "name" or "term" used for when a person does this with an object's properties (a name for when a person creates the property outside of the braces rather than inside?  Or is this just a random unnamed technique?

Comment: I never heard a name for that. Why would the distinction matter?

Comment: It's called "adding a property to an object".

Comment: There is no specific name. You can make one up, we won't laugh

Comment: I would simply call it property assignment, as opposed to object assignment using an object literal.

Comment: The distinction matters (to me at least) because they are two different ways of doing something and they are done completely differently and it could be worth it to label both ways of doing it *for reference purposes*.  As for it being called "adding a property to an object", that's not really what I was looking for.  Thanks everyone for the help.  I guess there is no actual term or word.

Answer (score 1):

I would say a dynamic assignment. It is when you are allowed to add properties after the object (or class, in other programming languages) was defined.

For exemple, in ActionScript, you have to tell an object is "dynamic" to be allowed to do that.

In Objective-C, you can dynamically handle cases where you assign properties or use methods that do not exist.

Usually, the keyword that comes out is "dynamic" in all those cases.